# My UV layout is distorted compared to the geometry of my object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

After unwrapping my UV layout is not projected to the UV plane. How can I rotate it to fit the image ?

[image]

I have now attached the blend file – Jan Scherders

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to scale the uv unwrap to fill the texture? Or are you asking how to get a circular projection?

Comment: Did you unwrap and then open that image in the image-editor or did you open the image and then unwrap?

Comment: I first unwrapped (project from view) and then opened that image. I have now attached the blend file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you unwrap an object and then add an image, the UV unwrapping will be adjusted to the aspect ratio of the image. So if you unwrap in the default square UV area and then open a rectangular image your UVs will be stretched/squashed.

Blender has an option when unwrapping called 'Correct Aspect' which should fix your exact problem. 'Correct Aspect' looks at the selected image node in the object's material and uses that to remove this stretching/squashing effect. However - it doesn't seem to like the ngon at the centre of that circle you are unwrapping.

So:

1. Select the ngon and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>> Poke Faces to triangulate it.
2. Press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap and, immediately after unwrapping, open the toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) in the 3D view and turn on 'Correct Aspect' or press <kbd>F6</kbd> to access the same options.

Comment: @JanScherders As a side note, when you comment on your own question and want to notify me, you have to mention '@RayMairlot', otherwise I don't get a notification. On this answer you don't have to @ me, it will notify me automatically as the post you're commenting on is mine.

Comment: This time I first tested your answer and it works !! Great !! Thanks a lot. This is really something you have to know

Comment: I have made a correction as I found the real cause of the problem.

Comment: This works too. I like your more fundamental analysis and solution. It also makes me understand things better

Comment: by the way ... why is the flash on the back not "perfect" (there is a black line on the left when rendered) ?

Comment: I'm not actually sure what is going on, this seems to solve your specific case, but I'm not entirely sure why. As for the flash, I'm not sure, that is a separate problem for a separate question.

Comment: @JanScherders If possible, I would like to upload the blend file you provided to the blender bug tracker as there's something I just don't understand about your file. I would of course, remove any images you have included, I just need to use that circular mesh.

Comment: That's OK to upload my file to the blender bug tracker